# Join tables with different colums to single colum

Tags: mysql

First off, for categorization purposes, could someone figure out a better name to index this as?

Secondly, I have a table and I want to grab the username from another table to two columns on the same table.

```
SELECT ignite_board.*,username AS 'name'
FROM ignite_board,user_info 
WHERE bnumber = 3 
AND ignite_board.uid = user_info.id 
ORDER BY POSITION
```

Gets me this:

```
ID    bnumber  position  UID  qual  time        following  name  
1176  3        1         442  2     1382045726  440        bb1   
1177  3        2         445  2     1382045936  442        bb4   
1181  3        3         450  2     1382050220  449        bb6   
1178  3        4         446  2     1382050371  439        aa2   
1209  3        5         466  1     1382050130  450        bb8   
1212  3        6         469  2     1382050502  467        bb10  
1210  3        7         467  1     1382050172  466        bb9   
1232  3        8         475  1     1382050415  446        aa7   
1180  3        9         444  0     1382045690  445        bb3   
1214  3        10        471  0     1382050220  466        bb11  
1233  3        11        476  0     1382050415  475        aa8   
1179  3        12        441  0     1382045562  475        aa1   
1182  3        13        452  0     1382046032  448        aa6   
1216  3        14        473  0     1382050272  469        bb12  
1234  3        15        477  0     1382050502  469        bb16  
1271  3        16        454  0     1382306814  442        bb7
```

But what would I need to get the username and the Following username (sorta like this)

```
SELECT ignite_board.*,username AS 'name',username AS 'following' 
FROM ignite_board,user_info 
WHERE bnumber = 3 
AND ignite_board.uid = user_info.id 
AND ignite_board.following = user_info.id 
ORDER BY POSITION
```

Comment: Both of you are right, I gave it to the person who answered first though. 
Thanks much guys!

Comment: Unless you really know what you're doing (and it's clear that you don't) you should avoid implicit (comma-style) joins. Always use 'explcit' JOIN syntax instead, as per my example. This makes queries much easier for us humans to a) understand and b) adapt.

Comment: Yeah, I'll go ahead and blame my sub adequate professor on that one. I had a feeling there was a better way to do it, and we were being taught the shortcut method that just ... "worked" more or less. Good thing to know for future records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT b.*
     , u.username name
     , f.username following
  FROM ignite_board b
  JOIN user_info u
    ON u.id = b.uid 
  JOIN user_info f
    ON f.id = b.following 
 WHERE bnumber = 3 
 ORDER 
    BY position;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to join the `user_info` table twice, and give a different alias to each instance:

```
SELECT ignite_board.*,u.username AS 'name',f.username AS 'following' 
FROM ignite_board,user_info u, user_info f
WHERE bnumber = 3 
AND ignite_board.uid = u.id 
AND ignite_board.following = f.id 
ORDER BY POSITION
```